# Nods to other sci-fi shows in "Childhood's End" miniseries

Tags: arthur-c-clarke, childhoods-end

I was watching the first part of the [Childhood's end](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4146128/) miniseries today, and I caught a few *nods* to other sci-fi shows:

1. [Battlestar Galactica](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407362/) is shown playing on a TV at *00:02:29* minute mark, and a still a few minutes later:

[image: Battlestar Galactica]

2. The song played on this scene *( 00:14:10 minute mark )* is the same ( or very similar ) to the one played on the end of the *war of Serenity valley* scene on [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0579535/) episode of [Firefly](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/?ref_=tt_ov_inf).

[image]

I was wondering if there are any other that I missed ?

Comment: This was my favorite of his novels. Is the show any good?

Comment: @wogsland Yeah, I liked it :)